# Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to write with admin permission two places at once on firebase functions.
Getting this strange error:

> Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument  contains an invalid key (/Auction/TD6MKEhS/-Kn9cMUPkk)

My code is:

```
var newPostRef = admin.database().ref().child("History/" + this.customeruid + '/' + this.quoteid + '/' + this.banuid).push();
var newPostKey = newPostRef.key;
var updatedBidQuote = {};
// Create the data we want to update
let postData = { creationBidDate: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, customeruid: this.banuid, quoteCompanyCreatoruid: this.customeruid, Amount: this.banBid };
updatedBidQuote['/Auction/' + this.customeruid + '/' + this.quoteid] = postData;
updatedBidQuote['/History/' + this.customeruid + '/' + this.quoteid + '/' + this.banuid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;
return admin.database().ref().set(updatedBidQuote);
```

I check the object of postData and didnt have any (.keys or strange value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only pass full paths into `update`, so the last line should be:

```
return admin.database().ref().update(updatedBidQuote)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had unnecessary curly brackets. I changed from

```
return admin.database().ref().update( {updateObj} );
```

to

```
return admin.database().ref().update(updateObj);
```